# How to determine equivalence classes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let the relation $µ$ on $Z$ (set of integers) be defined by $xµy$ if and only if $x^2 ≡ y^2(mod 4).$

I have already proven that the relation $µ$ is an equivalence relation, but I am currently struggling with determining the equivalence classes

Do I just testing values for $x \in Z$?

For example:

If $x ≡ 0 (mod 4)$, then $x^2 ≡ 0^2 ≡ 0 (mod 4)$. So, the equivalence class [x] contains all integers that are congruent to $0$ modulo $4$.

If $x ≡ 1 (mod 4)$, then $x^2 ≡ 1^2 ≡ 1 (mod 4).$ The equivalence class [x] contains all integers that are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

Therefore, the equivalence classes of the relation $µ$ on $Z$ are:

$[0] = \{..., -8, -4, 0, 4, 8, ...\}$

$[1] = \{..., -7, -3, 1, 5, 9, ...\}$

Is this correct? But I believe that my equivalence classes need to complete $Z$? Not sure if I am doing the right thing. And where is $2$?

Answer (score 2):

Actually,
$$
x\mathrel\mu 0\iff x^2\equiv0\pmod4\iff x\text{ is even},
$$
and therefore $[0]$ is the set of all even integers.

And
$$
x\mathrel\mu 1\iff x^2\equiv1\pmod4\iff x\text{ is odd,}
$$
and therefore $[1]$ is the set of all odd integers.

Since every integer is even or odd, you are done: these are the only equivalence classes.

---

Here's another way of reaching the same conclusion. If $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$, then
\begin{align}
x\mathrel\mu y&\iff x^2\equiv y^2\pmod4\\
              &\iff4\mid(x-y)(x+y).
\end{align}
Now, when a product of integers is a multiple of $4$, then either both factors are even or one of them is odd whereas the other one is a multiple of $4$. But the current situation the second possibility cannot occur. Indeed, if, say $x+y$ is odd, the $x-y$ is odd too, since it is equal to $(x+y)-2y$. So, both $x+y$ and $x-y$ are even, and this means that $x$ and $y$ have the same parity. So,
\begin{align}
[x]&=\{y\in\mathbb{Z}\,|\,x\text{ and }y\text{ have the same parity}\}\\
   &=\begin{cases}
       \{\text{even integers}\}&\text{ if $x$ is even}\\
       \{\text{odd integers}\}&\text{ if $x$ is odd.}
     \end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just one more question, which is kinda unrelated, is μ anti symmetry? From my proof, I think so, but I am not sure.

Comment: No, it is not: $0\mathrel\mu2$ and $2\mathrel\mu0$, but $0\ne2$.

Answer (score 0):

We denote
$$[\ell]_{\mathbb{Z}_4}:=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}:n\equiv \ell\mbox{ mod } 4\},\qquad\ell=0,1,2,3.$$
Then for each $m\in[\ell]_{\mathbb{Z}_4}$, there is $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $m=4k+\ell$. Therefore
$$m^2=(4k+\ell)^2=\ell^2.$$
Denote
$$[p]_{\mathbb{Z}_4,2}:=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}:n^2\equiv p^2 \mbox{ mod }4\}.$$
It follows from $0^2\equiv 2^2\equiv 0 \mbox{ mod 4}$ and $1^2\equiv 3^2\equiv 1 \mbox{ mod 4}$ that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
[0]_{\mathbb{Z}_4,2}=[0]_{\mathbb{Z}_4}\bigcup [2]_{\mathbb{Z}_4}\\
[1]_{\mathbb{Z}_4,2}=[1]_{\mathbb{Z}_4}\bigcup [3]_{\mathbb{Z}_4}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
and
$$[0]_{\mathbb{Z}_4,2}\bigcup[1]_{\mathbb{Z}_4,2}=\left([0]_{\mathbb{Z}_4}\bigcup [2]_{\mathbb{Z}_4}\right)\bigcup\left([1]_{\mathbb{Z}_4}\bigcup [3]_{\mathbb{Z}_4}\right)=\mathbb{Z}.$$